# "Invalid argument main.js" Gmap error in IE

Tags: 7, google-maps

I have [GMap Module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) and GMap Location version  6.x-1.1; in Internet Explorer (any version), on the GMap page I see this error:

> Message: Invalid argument.
>   Line: 401  //in IE8, and 942 in IE6 
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fa_ALL/mapfiles/310c/maps2.api/main.js

I found [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921528/some-google-map-markers-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer-but-show-up-in-all-ot), but the answer doesn't apply in my case, as the lat attribute is true.

What is problem?

Comment: May you report the used marker tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem.
in Gmap Module setting and Google Map Initialize check default center and enter valid  coordinates.
in my case default center was setted to 0,NAN. problem was with **NAN**.
at now it works in IE.